# I need to understand a line of code inside a contract => startTime: _startTime == 0 ? currentTime() : _startTime

Tags: solidity-0.5.x, datetime, time

I am reading a contract from this location :

https://gist.github.com/rstormsf/7cfb0c6b7a835c0c67b4a394b4fd9383

I am not able to understand the logic in the code line 72

```
startTime: _startTime == 0 ? currentTime() : _startTime,
```

Can somebody please explain ?

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
   if( _startTime == 0) {
      startTime = currentTime()
    } else {
      startTime = _startTime
    }
```

Comment: ok, thanks. But what is the syntax to use ?

Comment: In solidity, it's called Ternary operator https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/cheatsheet.html?highlight=Ternary%20operator#order-of-precedence-of-operators